# java8 - groupingby from a property inside an object

Tags: java, list, dictionary, java-8

I want to create a `Map<String,List<A>>` where A contains B and the groupby is made from a property from B.

```
public class A{
        private int a;
        private ...
        private B b;
}

public class B{
           private String name;
           private ... 
}
```

and I have a

```
List<A> alist;
```

and I want to do something like that :

```
Map<String, List<A>> resultmap = alist.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingby(B::getName()));
```

except this is not possible to access B.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You just need to write a lambda expression to access `b`:

```
Map<String, List<A>> resultMap = alist.stream()
                                      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(a -> a.getB().getName()));
```

Assuming there is a getter `getB()` to retrieve the `b` property, you can call that inside the lambda expression.

---

As a side-note, your current method-reference is invalid: you don't need the parentheses inside `B::getName()`.

Comment: My bad, automatic compression wasn't working and I tried many other complicated stream methods. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Hey, i have the same thing, and the lambda doesnt work for me, its like java dont recognize a in order to group by b. any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

You can do this with a lambda expression instead of a method reference :

```
Map<String, List<A>> resultmap =     
    alist.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingby(a->a.getB().getName()));
```

Comment: could u help please

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67719153/how-to-convert-list-of-nested-object-to-list-of-objects-with-similar-information

Answer (score 0):

In Java 8, you need to cast `a` as `A`:

```
Map<String, List<A>> resultmap =     
    alist.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingby(a->((A)a).getB().getName()));
```