# How to convert list of nested object to list of objects with similar informations using streams

Tags: java, data-structures, java-stream, collectors

I have this list of data

```
List<Status> statuses = [
    {
        id: 123
        mainSatus: HA
        MoreInfo: {
            name: max
            status: MM
        }
    },
    {
        id: 456
        mainSatus: HA
        MoreInfo: {
            name: max
            status: KK
        }
    },
    {
        id: 777
        mainSatus: OU
        MoreInfo: {
            name: max
            status: KK
        }
    }
];
```

I want to have an output like this

```
List<SimilarInfo> similarinfos = [{mainStatus:HA, statueses:[MM,KK]} , {mainStatus:OU, statuses:[KK]}];
```

So grouping by mainStatus with corresponding statuses.

Comment: please add the code you have been tried so far, to help you better

Comment: Do you have POJOs of `Status` `MoreInfo` `SimilarInfo` ? If so, can you add them to your question?

Comment: from the question its really clear what attributes are included i only need to group them

Comment: @AlexAlex is this a JSON or java object? or it doesn't matter to you?

Comment: Grouping them its an object

Comment: Please add complete code or remove your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
List<Status> statuses = Arrays.asList(
        new Status(123, "HA", new MoreInfo("max", "MM")),
        new Status(456, "HA", new MoreInfo("max", "KK")),
        new Status(777, "OU", new MoreInfo("max", "KK"))
);

Map<String, List<String>> mainStatusToStatuses = statuses.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Status::getMainStatus,
                Collectors.mapping(status -> status.getMoreInfo().getStatus(), Collectors.toList())));

System.out.println(mainStatusToStatuses);
```

Output:

```
{OU=[KK], HA=[MM, KK]}
```

If you are not satisfied with the map, you can do from here:

```
List<SimilarInfo> similarInfos = mainStatusToStatuses.entrySet().stream()
        .map(entry -> new SimilarInfo(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(similarInfos);
```

Output:

```
[SimilarInfo(mainStatus=OU, statuses=[KK]), SimilarInfo(mainStatus=HA, statuses=[MM, KK])]
```

Comment: Thanks is it possible to have it in one methode?

Comment: @AlexAlex Well, we can concat the two streams:        ` List<SimilarInfo> similarInfos = statuses.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Status::getMainStatus,
                        Collectors.mapping(status -> status.getMoreInfo().getStatus(), Collectors.toList())))
                .entrySet().stream()
                .map(entry -> new SimilarInfo(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());`